# Why does Magento remove my frontend cookie after using customer/session

Tags: frontend, cookie

I'm using Nginx and HHVM, I'm also using custom php files to interact with Magento.

When I run any PHP file the frontend cookie gets set properly, also the shoppingcart works fine.

However, whenever I use:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
$session->login($login, $pass);
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

The frontend cookie gets removed.

Question: why is that and what can I do to solve it?

Settings:
[image]

Complete example:

```
include_once('../app/Mage.php');
    ob_start();
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
    $login = $v[0]; //username as email
    $pass  = $v[1]; //user password
    try {
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
        $customer->website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
        $customer->loadByEmail($login);

        $session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
        $session->login($login, $pass);
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $returnJson['success']  = false;
        $returnJson['error']    = $e;
    }
```

Comment: The cookie domain is set with a store-view, but the script makes use of the admin-store? setCustomerAsLoggedIn() will renew sessions this results in deletion of frontend cookies. If then these sessions are not properly renewed, they might be just lost. But it's only a quick comment. You perhaps have found out some other details since march, so please share.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see of your post you would appear to be forcing a user to log in. However if this code is being executed outside of Magento then you are likely logging-in someone, whether or not they are logged-in already.

Consider changing the external code so that it uses the current session instead of generating a new one when they are already logged in. Then it should not generate a new cookie to reflect the new session.

```
   public function loginPostAction()
   {

     if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
         $this->_redirect('*/*/');
         return;
     }

    $session = $this->_getSession();
```

Try a check similar to that which is used in the login in Magento to prevent it.